# Count of specific value of column in group

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to achieve the following:

```py
aggregate_commitment_df = commitment_df.groupby("sprint_start_date", "squad").agg(
    stories_committed=pl.count(pl.col("issue_type") == "Story"),
    spikes_committed=pl.count(pl.col("issue_type") == "Spike"),
    bugs_committed=pl.count(pl.col("issue_type") == "Bug"),
    story_points_committed=pl.sum("story_points"),
)
```

where, for example, `stories_committed` will be the count of all rows with `issue_type == "Story"` for each `sprint_start_date` and `squad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [filter](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.filter.html) in the aggregation context before you use `count`.

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

commitment_df = pl.DataFrame({
    "sprint_start_date": [date(2023,8,1),date(2023,8,2),date(2023,8,3),] * 8,
    "squad": ["team1", "team2"] * 12,
    "issue_type": ["Story"] * 10 + ["Spike"] * 8 + ["Bug"] * 6, 
    "story_points": [*range(4)] * 6,
})

aggregate_commitment_df = commitment_df.groupby("sprint_start_date", "squad").agg(
    stories_committed=pl.col("issue_type").filter(pl.col("issue_type") == "Story").count(),
    spikes_committed=pl.col("issue_type").filter(pl.col("issue_type") == "Spike").count(),
    bugs_committed=pl.col("issue_type").filter(pl.col("issue_type") == "Bug").count(),
    story_points_committed=pl.sum("story_points"),
)

print(aggregate_commitment_df)
```

Results:

```
shape: (6, 6)
┌───────────────────┬───────┬───────────────────┬──────────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ sprint_start_date ┆ squad ┆ stories_committed ┆ spikes_committed ┆ bugs_committed ┆ story_points_committed │
│ ---               ┆ ---   ┆ ---               ┆ ---              ┆ ---            ┆ ---                    │
│ date              ┆ str   ┆ u32               ┆ u32              ┆ u32            ┆ i64                    │
╞═══════════════════╪═══════╪═══════════════════╪══════════════════╪════════════════╪════════════════════════╡
│ 2023-08-03        ┆ team2 ┆ 1                 ┆ 2                ┆ 1              ┆ 8                      │
│ 2023-08-02        ┆ team1 ┆ 1                 ┆ 2                ┆ 1              ┆ 4                      │
│ 2023-08-01        ┆ team1 ┆ 2                 ┆ 1                ┆ 1              ┆ 4                      │
│ 2023-08-03        ┆ team1 ┆ 2                 ┆ 1                ┆ 1              ┆ 4                      │
│ 2023-08-02        ┆ team2 ┆ 2                 ┆ 1                ┆ 1              ┆ 8                      │
│ 2023-08-01        ┆ team2 ┆ 2                 ┆ 1                ┆ 1              ┆ 8                      │
└───────────────────┴───────┴───────────────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if `pl.sum()` is deprecated in the future so I'd try to use `pl.col("story_points").sum()`